# Function which takes input parameter and returns the data is created with compilation errors

Tags: oracle, function, plsql

Create a Function named '`find_balance`' which takes `invoice_id` as input and returns the `balance_status` of type `varchar`.
Function name : `find_balance`
Input Parameter : `invoice_id` in `int`
Output variable : `balance_status` with data type `varchar`

**Design rules:**

1. If the balance of the given invoice id is equal to zero,then display the status as 'The payment has been Completed'
2. If the balance of the given invoice id is greater than zero,then display the status as amount 'yet to be paid' .   I wrote the below query:

---

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION find_balance (invoice_id IN INTEGER)  
   RETURN VARCHAR2  
IS  
   c_find_balance   NUMBER (5, 2);  
   balance_status  VARCHAR (255);  
BEGIN  
   SELECT find_balance  
     INTO c_find_balance  
     FROM shipment_entity  
    WHERE id = invoice_id;  

   IF c_find_balance == 0  
   THEN  
      balance_status := 'The payment has been Completed';  
   ELSE  
      IF c_find_balance > 0  
      THEN  
         balance_status := find_balance'yet to be paid';  
      END IF;  
   END IF;  

   RETURN (c_find_balance);  
END;  
/
```

Comment: First of all, you return `c_find_balance` which is a number. You probably want to return `balance_status`.

Comment: Furthermore, within your `ELSE` you say `balance_status := find_balance'yet to be paid'`. Maybe you mean `balance_status := TO_CHAR(c_find_balance) || ' yet to be paid`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're quite close to solution; I wonder why you didn't fix that yourselves.

Sample table & data:

```
SQL> create table shipment_entity
  2    (id number,
  3     find_balance number
  4    );

Table created.

SQL> insert into shipment_entity values (1, 100);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into shipment_entity values (2, 0);

1 row created.
```

Function: I marked what you did wrong (lines 5, 12, 18, 22):

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION find_balance (invoice_id IN INTEGER)
  2     RETURN VARCHAR2
  3  IS
  4     c_find_balance   NUMBER (5, 2);
  5     balance_status  VARCHAR2 (255);         --> VARCHAR2, not VARCHAR
  6  BEGIN
  7     SELECT find_balance
  8       INTO c_find_balance
  9       FROM shipment_entity
 10      WHERE id = invoice_id;
 11
 12     IF c_find_balance = 0                   --> =, not ==
 13     THEN
 14        balance_status := 'The payment has been Completed';
 15     ELSE
 16        IF c_find_balance > 0
 17        THEN
 18           balance_status := c_find_balance || ' yet to be paid';  --> missing concatenation; wrong variable name
 19        END IF;
 20     END IF;
 21
 22     RETURN (balance_status);                --> balance_status, not c_find_balance
 23  END;
 24  /

Function created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> select find_balance(1) res1,
  2         find_balance(2) res2
  3  from dual;

RES1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
RES2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
100 yet to be paid
The payment has been Completed


SQL>
```